# Manhwa where a girl dies because of a fairy that gives her some important power. She reincarnates as a plant mage

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, webcomics, reincarnation

It's about a girl who is reincarnated in a magic world as a plant mage (or something like that). She starts to grow fruits and vegetables to get money, because these are expensive in this world. There is a water mage who buys the food to give to his "boss" who is a future hero. He doesn't like to eat because of his traumatic past, but her food taste fresh enough for him to enjoy. He can communicate with fairies, the same as her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: @Josy - Do you recall the hair colour of the girl?

Answer (score 3):

This is *[The Cooking Wizard](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/d3vapk7)*.

> A food-loving tattooist, YooJung. After losing consciousness due to a sudden accident she opens her eyes to find herself **possessing ‘Sylvia’, a character from the novel** she read. In addition, she happens to meet ‘Felix’, the hero of the novel, who, **due to the abuse of his stepmother, suffers from anorexia** and will soon turn the continent into blood. In order to eat more delicious food, to cook more easily, Sylvia inscribes magic circles on to her body. The new magic circles that are born through her fingertips bring a new breeze to the continent where magic-beasts are rampant.

The story opens with the main character walking around a meat market after being transported to the world of a novel. One of the shopkeepers explicitly identifies her as a plant mage

[image: plant mage]

In a flash back to before she dies, in her original body she's eating a meal while reading a book about a prince that cannot eat, due to his stepmother poisoning his dishes. This is the trauma from the question.

[image: Poison]

She transmigrates after hearing a voice calling. She goes out of her apartment to investigate and trips over a fairy, and wakes up within the novel as a plant mage.

Produce is indeed expensive:

[image: produce too expensive for commoners]

She decides to use her powers as a plant mage to make her own food - she did not explicitly choose to become a plant mage, she was one before she knew anything about the world.

The water mage presumably appears later, but this is a perfect match within the first two chapters.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Fairy/ies` and `Food`